# XPATH - Selecting text within a node without a child

Tags: xml, xpath

I am really new to xpath and was hoping that I could get some guidance. I have the following XML:

```
<dd class="conten1">
    <li class="">
      <b> Some text here </b>
      <b> another text here </b>
      <span class="date-range">2014 – Present</span>
    </li>
</dd>
```

I have run the following xpath:

```
.//dd[contains(@class, 'conten1')]/li
```

and it returns:

> Some text here another text here2014 - Present

How do I remove the "span" portion and only get

> Some text here another text here

I have run

```
substring-before(.//dd[contains(@class, 'conten1')]/li,'201')
```

but this is not ideal as some of the entrees do not contain that span portion thus, would not be retrieved at all.

What I wish to grab is only the "Some text here another text here" portion consistently.

Really hope for some help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Try /text() on the end of your path...

Comment: Thank you for this and it helps a lot. What if the text comes in the following format

<b> text 1 </b>
<b> text 2 </b>
<span class = .......

For do I select all of the b

Comment: What is your criterion for knowing what to grab? Do you want all the text from `<b>` elements only? All the text from non-`<span>` elements? The XPath expression `'Some text here another text here'` will give you what you asked for, but I assume that's not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you need only the `b` nodes, then XPath may look like

```
//dd[contains(@class, 'conten1')]/li/b
```

If you need all nodes except the `span`, then the XPath may look like

```
//dd[contains(@class, 'conten1')]/li/*[name(.)!='span']
```

Comment: +1. I would replace the `*[name(.)!='span']` at the end with `*[not(self::span)]`, which may reduce string comparisons.